# How to avoid sending variable from view to controller in this example?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a View which calculates entries to be edited,deleted using javascript. The id's are calculated according to ticked checkboxes and are stored in an array which need to be sent to controller-method to either edit or delete...I read somewhere that ideally variables should not be sent from View to Controller in Codeigniter. How can i do it differently?

View

```
function checkedAll() {
    var rowlength=document.getElementById("check").rows.length; 
    z=document.getElementById("check").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked;

    for(var i=1;i<rowlength-1;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("check").getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked = z; 
    }
}

function del(){
    var rowlength=document.getElementById("check").rows.length;
    var id = new Array();

    for(var i=1;i<rowlength-1;i++)
    {
        var t = document.getElementById("check").getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked; 
    var y = document.getElementById("check").rows[i].cells;
        id[i]=y[0].innerHTML;
    }   
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
     <table id="check" >
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th> 
            <th>Name</th> 
            <th>Age</th> 
            <th>Qualification</th> 
            <th> <input type="checkbox" onclick='checkedAll()'/> </th>
        </tr>

        <?php 
        $check=0; 
        $flag=0;    
        $my_checkbox=array();

        foreach($forms as $ft): ?> 
            <tr id="<?php echo $check;?>" class="<?php echo $d ?>"> 
                <td > <?php echo $ft['serial']; ?> </td> 
                <td> <?php echo $ft['name'] ;?></td> 
                <td> <?php echo $ft['age'] ;?></td> 
                <td> <?php echo $ft['qualification'] ;?></td> 
                <td> <input type="checkbox" /></td>
            </tr>
            <?php $check++ ?>             
        <?php endforeach ?>

        <tr> 
            <td colspan="5" align="center"> 
                <button type="button" name="create" id='but' value="Create" 
                        onclick = "Redirect();" >Create </button>  
                <button type="button" name="edit" onclick="edit();" id='but' >Edit </button> 
                <button type="button" name="delete" id='but' onclick="del(); " >Delete </button>
            </td>
        </tr>   

    </table> 

    <form action="<?php $this->load->helper('url');echo site_url('form/edit');?>" method="POST"  id="myForm" >
        <input type="hidden" name="snap" id="snap">
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Of course you can send variables to the controller you either can use a normal GET request with the params on the url or you either can use a POST request, and post the variables to the controller

Comment: Another thing, you should load the helpers on your controller not on your view, so you should remove this "$this->load->helper('url')" from the view and paste it on the method that calls that view, or if you really use it a lot just autoload it

Comment: Yep,moved that helper to controller..how do you POST data from View to controller-method?

Comment: Whenever you submit a form the default action is POST. I've noticed that you have a form on your view but you don't have a submit button inside your form. You can also POST that with ajax but I don't know if you're comfortable with ajax

Comment: I have added a submit button,but something prevents data from POST - ing...i am not that proficient with ajax..

Comment: Solved it...got the form and send it by getElementById('form_name').submit() in the edit function script...Thnx a ton for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create method in the controller that accepts this array and processes it, use jquery ajax to send this data to a controller... no need for a reload, no problems with direct call.

On the other hand, you can create controller method which is called directly, and after processing array redirects back to the view to emulate staying there. I do not recommend this because it is 5-6 years old approach.

Drop me a comment if you need more detailed directions on this.

Here is example code:

```
var data = //your variable to be sent
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/controller/method",
    data: data,
    success: function(result) {
        // data is returned by controller

    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('ERROR');
        //for errors thrown by PHP exceptions and other backend features
        //or you can return result also and fetch an exception if you go for try - catch, which I highly recommend
    }
});
```

Comment: do I have to send the array from view to controller-method according to your first solution?

Comment: in both solution data needs to be sent for the processing, first method uses $.ajax jquery to send it asynchronously and second method loads the controller method.